# FileVisitor java memory usage and how it works

Tags: java, file-io, directory

So, usually if you want a list of all the files in a directory you can do

```
(Directory).listFiles();
```

or

```
(Directory).list();
```

With Directory being the variable name of the file.

But lets say the directory just has way too many files and those functions end up giving you some sort of out of memory exception.

So my question is can you use FileVisitor to walk the file tree without having that problem? Does FileVisitor use any type of structure thats a list or an array? From the docs it says it recursively visits all the files of the tree, could this throw any stack overflow errors if the directory is too big? Im just a little confused on how FileVisitor does what it does.

[docs.oracle-WalkingTheFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Comment: It will walk through the files on the filesystem, and for each file found it will call a `visit` method, allowing you to do something with the file found.  Once you exit the `visit` method it will call you again with the next file, etc.  As long as you finish doing whatever needs doing inside the visit method, it will take very little memory.  If you however store all files in a List in the visit method, then you will again have the same problem as before.

Comment: Im writing the names to a text file to index them.

Comment: That should be fine as long as you don't keep all the names in memory but store them right away to the text file in the `visit` method.

Comment: You'd have to have a buttload of files to run out of memory even with the naive approach.

Comment: Yeah I know @Kayaman but it was to happen, wanted to know how to handle it.

Comment: This seems like a premature optimization. That said, FileVisitor probably won’t keep every file of a directory in memory, but it’s not your only option. Methods like [Files.newDirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) or [Files.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) should be preferred over File methods. The latter specifically guarantees it will return “a lazily populated Stream,” which should put to rest your memory concerns.

Comment: @VGR Why should they be preferred? whats the tradeoffs from FileVisitor and DirectoryStream/list?

Comment: They should be preferred over java.io.File methods, which return null instead of throwing an exception and thus do not provide any information on why an operation might have failed.  Files.walkFileTree is okay, but it’s a bit of overkill for doing a simple listing, since it loads the attributes of every file it visits.